# Is it feasible to make long-range PC monitor display extender with pi and openHD?

Tags: pi-4, usb, hdmi, pi-zero-w-2

Wanted to ask more experienced users about the feasibility of this proposed project:

Use [OpenHD](https://openhd.gitbook.io/open-hd/) to transmit a PC monitor display wirelessly to another device (ie laptop).

My thought process is that since OpenHD is able to transmit video over far distances (compared to wireless HDMI distances seen on marketed products), this should be able to send a desktop display wirelessly to another display that is quite far away.

I am totally fine with lag and low frame rate, because the purpose is for viewing simple word documents on the sending display, just need to see the screen once it loads things like scroll down, next page, etc. Its not like I am wanting to enjoy a live action film at 4k res! :smiley:

My biggest question is whether the transmitting device (the raspberry pi) can receive a monitor display as input if I use an HDMI to USB adaptor with the USB fed into the pi.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you are proposing is unclear. If you want to input HDMI to a Pi this is not possible (at least without an external HDMI receiver).

Comment: The traditional way to display a PC monitor remotely is to use a remote desktop app that connects to the PC using TCP/IP, including wireless wifi.  Look for VNC or RDP that have both WIndows and Linux implementations.  Doing this requires the PC to enable a remote desktop server and the receiving system to have a compatible client app.  Note that, by design, there are many technical and legal problems with capturing commercial content from an HDMI output.